# Could not find and load main class HomeController when deploy to Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, heroku

This is my first time deploying to heroku. I trying to deploy Spring MVC with postgreSql project.

When i first deploying to heroku, it said i was missing the Procfile. then i added the Procfile with text that just like example in heroku website that looked like this

> "web:    java -cp target/classes:"target/dependency/*" HomeController"

There is "HomeController". Here is what inside HomeController.java

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {

        return "home";
    }

}
```

which is this controller direct root of domain to my home.html. I have package just like "co.id.myproject.controller" in here i put my "HomeController.java"

and then when i running my application in heroku, it won't work. then i looked into heroku logs, with command prompt in cmd "Heroku logs", i found an error message that said

> "could not find or load main class HomeController"

I already define the HomeController in Procfile. What i missed here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `main` method in there. You have to specify the class with your main method in the configuration file for Heroku. Also you have to specify the full qualified name of the class in the run command.

Comment: how to do that? since my application is Spring MVC. Can u give me the example for main method for spring mvc?

Comment: If you are not using Spring Boot, then you'll probably need a Servlet container. If you are deploying a WAR file you should read this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

Comment: i am not using Spring Boot and i dont build war to deploy to heroku, i tried, the war method is out dated i think, since is not working. so i commit as git project in my root of my application and then i push to heroku, since the push is a success, i just got that error

Comment: So how do you run your application? Did you even try to run it locally? If so, use the same method on Heroku.

Comment: yes, it work fine. i just add to tomcat server and when i execute my localhost:8080/myproject/ it just open up my index.html without any errors, i even try publish to openshift, and it work too. What i missed in heroku?